# How does adding noise to output avoid overfitting on training points?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Is adding noise to the output data used as a regularization technique to avoid overfitting on training data?

How does it reduce the generalization error and help regularization because as far as I know regularization is something which is directly linked to the complexity of our model.

How does it relate to the complexity of the trained model?

Answer (score 3):

**Why does it prevent overfitting?**

Noise destroys information. Your data becomes harder to fit, thus harder to over-fit. The extreme case is pure noise and your classifier will learn to ignore the input and predict a fixed probability for each class. That's the opposite of overfitting: on your validation set you will reach the exact same performance as during training.

**Why does this help with generalization?**

By adding noise you augment the training set with additional information. You tell your NN that the kind of noise you're adding should not change its prediction much. If this is true, then it will generalize better because it has learned about a larger part of the input space. If it is false it can actually make generalization worse, for example if you're learning the XOR function from a 10-bit input.

**Output Noise**

(Update: oh, you're specifically asking about adding noise *to the outputs*. I don't know if this is common, but I see how it can help:)

The typical loss functions (e.g. cross-entropy) will give a very large penalty for wrong predictions if they are made with high confidence. During overfitting the network finds a lot of perfect predictors (a complex model will start to memorize each training input). Weights will be tuned to increase the confidence without bounds. Adding noise to the output prevents that, by teaching the network that it can never make a high-certainty prediction. This will soften the high penalty for errors made on the validation set. It will also prevent destructive weight updates that only served to add false confidence.

Answer (score 1):

> Is adding noise to the output data used as a regularization technique
>   to avoid overfitting on training data?

Short answer is yes, and [@maxy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519886/10886420) points out correctly why. And I assume you meant adding noise to the input data of the model, not to the output of your model, though such techniques could be employed as well (topic for different discussion).

> How does it reduce the generalization error and help regularization
>   because as far as I know regularization is something which is directly
>   linked to the complexity of our model.

It may or may not help generalization, extreme noise case was brought up already by the aforementioned answer.

### Relation of data transformations by neural network and generalization

Generally, for high dimensional input (say `300` features or image) it is assumed that necessary information lies on low-dimensional [**manifold**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). Image below should help intuitive understanding of the idea (image from [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html)):

[image: manifold]

As one can see, even though original data is in three dimensions it may be presented pretty well in two dimensions. That's what neural network does, it transforms input data into another data representation (sometimes of higher dimensionality) to allow for task solution (e.g. transforming image by subsequent layers so they are linearly separable for classification in the last layer).

But how does it relate to noise? Neural networks are powerful fitters (complex model, will move to that), so if there is not enough data points it can learn a transformation (manifold) which isn't as smooth and nice as presented in the image. When the network is trained without augmentation and gets pretty similar input during test phase it may transform it wrongfully into totally different space region and may classify it incorrectly.

When noise is added, more data points representing the class are seen by neural network so it has to learn to create smoother data representation, where small variations in input do not change it's output tremendously.

Finally, `test` and `train` are assumed to come from the same (or pretty similar at least) distribution. When we learn better distribution of `train` by noise, chances to understand `test` increase as well, hence it usually helps generalization.

> How does it relate to the complexity of the trained model?

### Complexity of functions space

Neural networks are great at approximation and space of functions those can learn is huge (large space of functions can be considered as complexity). Now many functions (transformations) of input data may do good job for task at hand (let's stick with classification from now on).

Without augmentation or regularization, neural network has no incentive to learn less complicated functions which probably have higher chance to represent true transformation better (as per [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)). When noise is added many complicated functions are no longer a viable option as they highly depend on small variations of input. Hence, after noise is employed **neural networks are probably less complex in function space** (same goes for things like `dropout`, weight decay and others).

### Complexity of model

This one is not changed by the noise, as the architecture is predefined. Only weights are more "reasonable" (e.g., on extreme, no weight has `1000` or `-1000` values as those would amount for too high variance for single feature), as described above actually.

Comment: I exactly mean the addition of noise to the outputs and not to the inputs.I understand completely why adding noise to the inputs does make sense.